# how to charge a steel ball

Tags: charge

I have a 2 mm radius steel ball and I want to charge it in a 0.025 Coulomb charge. Can I do that domestically or the charge is too high? And how can I do that assuming I don't have another conductive material that I know it's charge?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not if you value your life!. The [capacitance of a sphere](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capsph.html) is given by :-

\$C=4\pi\epsilon_0R\$

The voltage on a capacitor is given by :-

\$V=\dfrac{Q}{C}\$

Putting your figures into those equations we find that the capacitance of your sphere is about 0.22pF and the voltage required for that much charge would be 110GV!

*Edit ...*

If you had another conductive object, you could make a two-plate capacitor in which case the required voltage could be *much* lower, so in *theory* you could charge a two plate capacitor using a much lower voltage, then move the other plate away and this would leave your original sphere charged, but this charge would soon leak away.

Comment: so if I put 110GV through that ball it's charge would be 0.025 Colon? I soppose that won't be easy... and there is no other practical way?

Comment: If the steel ball can be close to another conductive object iit can be done.

Comment: but that condactive object has to have charge... how do I charge that object?

Comment: The [Van de Graaf generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) is the best kind of experiment to show how this works.

Comment: but how could I know that I reached the wanted charge?

Comment: In theory, you can separate the plates of the capacitor, but it would take 900 billion pounds of force (using [F=Q^2/eps*A](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091230002500AAoIvcY))

Comment: @Someonation: probably because the steel ball fires off in a random direction at a few dozen kilometers per second.

Comment: Rule of thumb for having a spark (=discharge) in normal air is about 1kV/mm. So if your experiment is in the open air then you're talking about 110km separation between the two conductors ;o)